# Get UPNSuffixes In a different domain

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to remove all PNSUFFIXES in a different domain.
I run this code

```
$namedomaincontroller = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -Domain $ComboBox.selectedItem).name
Enter-PSSession $namedomaincontroller
$UPNSuffixes = Get-ADForest| select UPNSuffixes -ExpandProperty UPNSuffixes
$UPNSuffixes


Foreach ($GUPN in $UPNSuffixes)

{

$ComboBox2.Items.Add($GUPN);

}

    Exit-PSSession
```

But I'm doing the previous one because I'm using a user in another domain the previous one did not run and get an erro

Comment: Either use credntials that are vlid or create a credential object and supply credentials for your PSSession that are valid in the other domain.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove all PNSUFFIXES in a different domain.

Use [Set-ADForest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adforest?view=win10-ps) to remove all UPNSuffixes for a different domain.

```
Set-ADForest -Credential "Domain01\User01" -Identity fabrikam.com -UPNSuffixes $null
```

> The Identity parameter specifies the Active Directory forest to modify.

> -Credential
>
> Specifies the user account credentials to use to perform this task.
>
> If the acting credentials do not have directory-level permission to perform the task, Active Directory PowerShell returns a terminating error.

> To clear all values:
>
> -UPNSuffixes $Null